# How I can get the slot name in which the component is rendered

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I want to create a high order component which renders differently depending in which slot the component is. Is there any service where I can get the information in which slot the component is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the ancestor `PageSlotComponent` in your custom component and get the slot name by accessing its public property `position$: Observable<string>`:

```js
export class CustomComponent {
  constructor(@Optional() protected pageSlotComponent: PageSlotComponent) {}
  /*...*/

  slot$ = this.pageSlotComponent.position$;
}
```

Explanation:

- In Angular you can inject the closest parent component of a given type, by passing it as a constructor dependency.
- You might want to add `@Optional()` decorator if you plan to use your component outside the content slot (i.e. as a static component). It will help avoid crashing app in the runtime, but will just resolve `PageSlotComponent` instance safely to null.

Comment: Thank you very much. The position$ observable is protected, but the getter "position" of this class provides the value of the protected observable.